# Unable to restart custom slideshow(Vegas Background Slideshow) after reaching the end

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, slideshow

I implemented the **vegas bg slideshow** successfully in my wordpress template. Everything works fine besides that the slideshow does not loop.

It stops with the last image in queue. Is that how it's supposed to be? 
I expected it to loop by default. I can not find any documentation about a loop setting.

Does anyone know a workaround to loop the slideshow? Like to catch a onfinished event...

[Here](http://traeumer.com/wp/) is the link to the page.

Any hint is welcome and appreciated.

Comment: I checked the documentation of the plugin. The demo does loop.
See  http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/documentation/settings/

Comment: Yes, I know the demo does loop. But I can just find a loop parameter for video. ( video.loop )  And thats still in experimental implementeation mode. Maybe something breaks my jquery code. But I already deaktivated all other plugins and also checked the firebug console for errors.

Comment: Have you solved your problem? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I solved the problem. Make sure to set poster=no. If poster is set to yes the plugin stops looping  and sets the last slide as a poster. Its kind of confusing...

hope that helps

cheers